# msmtp installed as a system account not working with libsecret

Tags: password, email, keyrings

I have successfully setup a system config to send emails using msmtp.  Below is the configuration (located in **/etc/msmtprc**).

```
account default
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile        /var/log/msmtp

# gmail
host           smtp.gmail.com
port           587
from           <account>@gmail.com
user           <account>
password       <password>

# Syslog logging with facility LOG_MAIL instead of the default LOG_USER
syslog LOG_MAIL
```

I wanted to use libsecret to not have the password showing, so I did the following

```
secret-tool store --label=msmtp host smtp.gmail.com service smtp user <account>
```

I verified that the password was stored by typing:

```
secret-tool lookup host smtp.gmail.com
```

I then modified **/etc/msmtprc** as follows:

```
account default
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile        /var/log/msmtp

# gmail
host           smtp.gmail.com
port           587
from           <account>@gmail.com
user           <account>

# Syslog logging with facility LOG_MAIL instead of the default LOG_USER
syslog LOG_MAIL
```

This is not working.

If I dump **/var/log/msmtp** I get the following:

> Nov 12 14:36:30 host=smtp.gmail.com tls=on auth=on user= from=@gmail.com recipients= smtpstatus=535 smtpmsg='535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials n10sm6743893wrv.77 - gsmtp' errormsg='authentication failed (method PLAIN)' exitcode=EX_NOPERM

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the file /etc/msmtprc I replaced *password* with *passwordeval*, pointing this to the libsecret command to extract the password.

```
account default
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile        /var/log/msmtp

# gmail
host           smtp.gmail.com
port           587
from           <account>@gmail.com
user           <account>
passwordeval   "secret-tool lookup host smtp.gmail.com"

# Syslog logging with facility LOG_MAIL instead of the default LOG_USER
syslog LOG_MAIL
```